# Socket.io how to implement a wss connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm making an authentication service with sockets on node.js with socket.io.

My question is: Which is the way to implement or create a wss connection on server and client side?

My code:

```
// Server
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io"); 

var app = express();

var port = 5310;
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening to requests on port", port);
});

var io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // Code
});
```

```
// Client
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5310");

// Code
```

Answer (score -1):

At the root level of your node application, create a `socket.js` file.

```
let io;

module.exports = {
    init: httpServer => {
        io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
        return io;
    },
    getIO: () => {
        if(!io) throw new Error('Socket.io not initialized');
        return io;
    }
};
```

This will create a kind of Singleton Design Pattern, meaning that you will never have more than one instance of your socket.

Now, in the App.js file, you will have this

```
const server = app.listen(8080);
        const io = require('./socket').init(server);
        io.on('connection', socket => {
            console.log("Connected!");
        })
```

Now, in your controller (assuming you use the MVC pattern), import your socket.js file and emit your action. Let's say you want to sent a message.

```
io.getIO().emit('messages', {
            action: 'send',
            message: //message data
        });
```

This should be everything regarding your backend. On the client-side, import your socket-client `const openSocket = require('socket.io-client');`, and listen for your action:

```
const socket = openSocket(yourServer);
        socket.on('messages', data => {
            if(data.action === 'send') {
                // do your logic
                // you have acces to data.message, containing your message data you passed on the server
            }
        })
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: How does this implement a `WSS:` connection?